# How to start two process at the same time and then wait both completed?

Tags: java, concurrency

I want to start two process at the same time and make sure complete them all before proceeding other steps. Can you help? I already tried Thread, it can't start two at the same time and wait until been done.

```
    final CyclicBarrier gate = new CyclicBarrier(3);
    Thread r2 = new Thread()
    {

        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                int i = 0;
                while (i < 3)
                {
                    System.out.println("Goodbye, " + "cruel world!");
                    Thread.sleep(2000L);
                    i++;
                    gate.await();
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException iex)
            {
            }
        }
    };

    Thread r3 = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                int i = 0;
                while (i < 3)
                {
                    System.out.println("Goodbye, " + "cruel world!");
                    Thread.sleep(2000L);
                    i++;
                    gate.await();
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException iex)
            {
            }
        }
    };

    r2.start();
    r3.start();
    gate.await();
    System.out.println("Donew");
```

Comment: Please show what research you have done and what you have tried.  Thanks.

Comment: You say you already tried using `Thread`. Can you show us the code you experimented with? That'll make more clear what you have tried and (if you explain it) what it is you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are repeatedly waiting for three parties, but only two threads are calling `await()` repeatedly. I would expect your code to immediately print, "Goodbye, cruel world!" twice, and "Done", then hang, because the loops are waiting for a third thread to invoke `await()` again, but the main thread has now terminated.

One solution is for your main thread to loop, invoking `await()` the same number of times that your task does. But that would be kind of ugly.

I'd suggest using the `invokeAll()` method of an `ExecutorService`. This will submit your tasks to the service at (approximately) the same time, then block until all tasks complete. If you want to try to improve the simultaneity of the task commencing, you could add a `CyclicBarrier`, but it looks like you are more concerned with when the tasks end, and `invokeAll()` will take care of that for you.

```
final class Sample
  implements Callable<Void>
{

  private static final int ITERATIONS = 3;

  private static final long AVG_TIME_MS = 2000;

  public static void main(String[] args)
    throws InterruptedException
  {
    List<Sample> tasks = Arrays.asList(new Sample(), new Sample());
    ExecutorService workers = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(tasks.size());
    for (int i = 1; i <= ITERATIONS; ++i) {
      /* invokeAll() blocks until all tasks complete. */
      List<Future<Void>> results = workers.invokeAll(tasks);
      for (Future<?> result : results) {
        try {
          result.get();
        }
        catch (ExecutionException ex) {
          ex.getCause().printStackTrace();
          return;
        }
      }
      System.out.printf("Completed iteration %d.%n", i);
    }
    workers.shutdown();
    System.out.println("Done");
  }

  @Override
  public Void call()
    throws InterruptedException
  {
    /* The average wait time will be AVG_TIME_MS milliseconds. */
    ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
    long wait = (long) (-AVG_TIME_MS * Math.log(1 - random.nextDouble()));
    System.out.printf("Goodbye, cruel world! (Waiting %d ms)%n", wait);
    Thread.sleep(wait);
    return null;
  }

}
```

Notice how I spiced things up with a random wait time. Yet, `invokeAll()` waits until all of tasks in that iteration complete.

Comment: `Thread.join()` is the way to go.  CyclicBarrier is a little overly heavy-weight in this case for my taste.

Comment: We don't really know what the case is. `CyclicBarrier` might be useful if tasks are being executed repeatedly. Creating new threads just for the convenience of their `join()` method might be wasteful.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Thread.join()`to wait until your subprocesses/threads have finished.
You should not need `CyclicBarrier`.

Answer (score -3):

1. It's impossible for the single processor machines.
2. Even if you find lot of answers on threads its not gonna start two process at the same time
3. If you accept the [Relative Simultanity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity) that will be easy.

Comment: The OP mentions nothing of how many processors.  And although this may be technically true, to the application it is easy to have things seem to happen at the same time, even on a single processor.  Regardless, it doesn't address the question.